# How To Send Query To MySQL From Java Using utf8_general (text type)

Tags: java, mysql

I am programming a new app in Java that has a login screen. It is working 100% !

This is the class to check if there is a connection to MySQL.

```
package Classes;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DBConnect {
    public Connection con;
    public Statement st;
    public ResultSet rs;

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public void DBConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error :- " + ex + " , Please Connect Support Team For More Info !", "DataBase", 0);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flipsoftwere", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException ex2) {
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 20));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "فشل الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات" + "\n" + "تئكد من ان الشبكة تعمل بشكل جيد أو اتصل بفريق الدعم", "قاعدة البيانات", 0);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

And It Is Working Like This And It Is Ok:- [Hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K5qf.png)

This is the code for the login form wen I press the login button :-

```
try {
    String usernameGET , PasswordGET;
    usernameGET=(String) userN.getSelectedItem();
    PasswordGET=userP.getText();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = '" + usernameGET + "';";

    db.rs = db.st.executeQuery(query);
    db.rs.next();
    String namec= db.rs.getString("UserName");
    String Pass= db.rs.getString("Password");

    if(usernameGET.equals(namec)){
        if(PasswordGET.equals(Pass)){
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 20));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "اهلا بك  " + usernameGET + " !","دخول مقبول",1);
            DashBord das=new DashBord();
            LogIn.statas.setText("Yes");
            this.setVisible(false);
            das.NameLogIn.setText(usernameGET);
            das.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 20));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"كلمة المرور خطأ","دخول مرفوض", 0);
        }
    }
    else {
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 20));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"اسم المستخدم خطأ","دخول مرفوض", 0);
    }
}catch(Exception ex3){
    UIManager.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT, 20));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex3);
}
```

If I choose (Adeeb) it works without a problem, like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO038.png)

But if I use a type of text ("اديب") like this, it is giving me a query error like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgPqQ.png) image !

So how can I send a query with text not in English ?

Comment: Looks like the SQL query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = 'اديب'` is not returning any rows. Can you verify this?

Comment: Will If I choosed any another word like 'admin'      SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = 'admin' It's Working but if I set it 'اديب' It's Not !

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE UserName = 'اديب'` It will return 0 (zero) because `اديب` does not exist in your database and that's why your java code is not working. Method `next()` in interface `ResultSet` returns `boolean`. This line of the code you posted is returning _false_: `db.rs.next();`